# Как прослушивать последний элемент ListView?

Tags: android

Как прослушивать последний элемент ListView?

Есть допустим 10 элементов. Как поймать тот момент когдаа 10 элемент находиться на экране?

Или когда listview достиг конца ?

Comment: начните с разбора https://habrahabr.ru/post/135226/ или объясните зачем Вам нужно знать, что элемент отображается.

Comment: @KoVadim,Pull-To-Refresh Это не то. Мне нужно динамическое добавление элементов как в ВК. Листаешь вниз они грузяться и добавляются

Comment: Вот это и нужно писать в вопросе!

Comment: учту на будущее

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalItem) {
            if(firstVisible + visibleCount == totalItem){
            //то что нужно тебе
            }
        }
    });
```

Если тебе нужно сделать подгрузку данных в listView, например по 10 элементов, то можешь сделать так: создаешь `Boolean isLoad = false`, и в условие добавляешь `if((firstVisible + visibleCount == totalCount) && (isLoad) && (totalCount>0))`, если условие выполняется то `вызываешь метод для получения следующих 10 элементов списка (либо как тебе удобно) и делаешь isLoad = false;` , а после добавления следующих элементов делаешь `isLoad = true`

Comment: Это же не сколько раз вызывается?. Раз 4-20.
Может есть другой способ?

Comment: А если положить в footer кнопку. И сделать так чтобы эту кнопку прослушивать. Тогда когда она видна на экране. ТОгда и сделать то что надо и вызовется только 1 раз

Comment: изменил ответ .